# Updating Broken Data Validation Lists via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object, range

I have a spreadsheet with several validation lists, one of which is linked to conditional formatting to identify the status of the record, "closed", "open", "pending", etc.  The sptreadsheet is rather large and with deleting and inserting rows over time the conditional formating status data validation list for some rows is broken.

My manual cleanup process is time consuming and I am trying to recreate the broken rows programmatcally via vba.  This code snippet works, but ths is hard coded and I would have to change each range reference manually each time.

```
Sub updateDataValidationRecords()

Range("A7").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
Formula1:="=Status"

End Sub
```

Question:

Is there a way to have a variation of the code above where I could provide a single cell address and based upon that cell address, add the correesponding data validation lists for  the other cells that need the data validation lists in the same row?

Thank you in advance for your help, it's appreciated.

Comment: For continuous cells: `Range("A7:H7").Validation.Add Type:=...`

For non-continuous cells: `Range("A7,C7,E7").Validation.Add Type:=...`

Comment: Conditional formatting and data validation are two different things. Conditional formatting tends to get corrupted, regarding data validation I haven't experienced that. If you want to fix conditional formatting you have to use the `FormatConditions` object of the range. I would re-apply the format condition to the whole range - not just the broken ranges.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood you question right, but this might work as you described.

```
Sub updateDataValidationRecordsBasedOnCell(Optional cellAddress As String)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim validationRange As Range
Dim rowDataRange As Range

' Set the worksheet where you want to apply the data validation
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") ' Replace "YourSheetName" with the actual sheet name

' If cellAddress is not provided, ask the user for input
If cellAddress = "" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    cellAddress = InputBox("Enter cell address:", "Cell Address", ActiveCell.Address)
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

' Exit the sub if the user cancels the InputBox
If cellAddress = "" Then Exit Sub

' Set the validation range based on the provided cell address
Set validationRange = ws.Range(cellAddress)

' Clear existing data validation in the specified range
validationRange.Validation.Delete

' Determine the entire row for data validation starting from column A
Set rowDataRange = ws.Rows(validationRange.Row)

' Add data validation to the entire row based on the named range "Status"
With rowDataRange.Validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Status"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    ' You can customize other validation properties here if needed
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

might work this for your case:

```
Sub updateDataValidationRecordsBasedOnCell(cellAddress As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim validationRange As Range
    Dim rowDataRange As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to apply the data validation
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheetName") ' Replace "YourSheetName" with the actual sheet name
    
    ' Set the validation range based on the provided cell address
    Set validationRange = ws.Range(cellAddress)
    
    ' Clear existing data validation in the specified range
    validationRange.Validation.Delete
    
    ' Determine the entire row for data validation starting from column A
    Set rowDataRange = ws.Rows(validationRange.Row)
    
    ' Add data validation to the entire row based on the named range "Status"
    With rowDataRange.Validation
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:="=Status"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        ' You can customize other validation properties here if needed
    End With
End Sub



Sub TestUpdateDataValidation()
    updateDataValidationRecordsBasedOnCell "A7"
    ' Change the cell address as needed
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, and I am very much the novice in Excel VBA.  The code you provided  works as designed and places the "Status" Data Validation (DV) list in each cell in row 7.  For my scenario, I have several different DV lists in specific cells in each row. The "Status" DV list is the only DV list tied to the Conditional Formatting.  So, if the current cell is "A7" then I would like to place the "Status" DV in cell "G7", "Division" DV list in cell "B7", "Mode" DV list in cell "Q7", etc.

Comment: Originally when I first ran into this issue I was thinking since the DV lists are at specific columns throughout the spreadsheet I would be able to provide a cell addreess value and the code would be able to take that value and offset placement of each DV list relative to that cell address.  So if I provided "A7" as rthe value in  "the sub "TestUpdateDataValidation" then it would place a specific DV list in whatever DV list names are in the With  ".Add Type:=xlValidateList" argument.

Comment: Question:  Is it possible to  have the "updateDataValidationRecordsBasedOnCell "A7"" reference the current cell address or to have an inputbox transfer the cell address to the "updateDataValidationRecordsBasedOnCell" function?  Thanks again for providing me help with this issue and I apologize if I was unclear in my original question.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try out your solution yet.  Thank you.  I did find a solution that works by , just as your more elegant solution does, use the InputBox function to identify the cells with the data validation updates.  Would you give me a little guidance on how I can comply with your request?  How do I assign the point total?

Comment: Just use one of the arrows at the top left of each answer to either upvote (if it was helpful) or downvote the corresponding answer."

Comment: Mark, I did as you suggested.  Is it standard for the upvote to only equate to a value of "1"?